# How to convert a string to a float in python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have the following code:

```
invoer = file_input().split("=")
fileinput=[float(i.replace(',', '.')) + 1 for i in invoer]
```

where `invoer` is:

```
>>> print invoer
['5,4 4,5 8,7', '6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3', '7,6', '9,8', '5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4']
```

However I cannot seem to get this in to a float.

Comment: can you show ur input data???

Comment: @Hackaholic: `invoer` is the input data, and the OP included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple numbers *per string*, so you'll need to split those on whitespace first:

```
[float(i.replace(',', '.')) + 1 for s in invoer for i in s.split()]
```

In a list comprehension sequential `for` loops should be read as nested loops; the outer loop is `for s in invoer`, then for each `s` we loop over `for i in s.split()`. Each `i` in that loop is converted to a float, then incremented by 1.

Demo:

```
>>> invoer = ['5,4 4,5 8,7', '6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3', '7,6', '9,8', '5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4']
>>> [float(i.replace(',', '.')) + 1 for s in invoer for i in s.split()] 
[6.4, 5.5, 9.7, 7.3, 4.2, 10.6, 5.3, 8.6, 10.8, 6.5, 8.8, 7.5, 7.4]
```